# Stargazer regression output: p-values in parantheses instead of se

Tags: r, stargazer

Is it possible to have p-values in the parentheses instead of being denoted as "p = ...." without having to change them manually? I want to show only the coefficient, significance stars, and p values in parentheses. Thanks

```
library(stargazer)
data("cars")
model <- lm(hp ~ wt, mtcars)
stargazer(model, type='text', report = ('vc*p'))
#> 
#> ===============================================
#>                         Dependent variable:    
#>                     ---------------------------
#>                                 hp             
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> wt                            46.160***                   
#>                             p = 0.00005       
#>                                                
#> Constant                      -1.821                   
#>                              p = 0.956         
#>                                                
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> Observations                    32             
#> R2                             0.434           
#> Adjusted R2                    0.415           
#> Residual Std. Error      52.437 (df = 30)      
#> F Statistic           22.999*** (df = 1; 30)   
#> ===============================================
#> Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: [‘stargazer’ is a terrible package.](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/comment/dkgw9q1/) I strongly recommend against using it. Use anything else instead, e.g. ‘[modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’. –